# fdisk -l hangs when USB SSD is plugged in

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a 500gb ssd in a seagate usb3 enclosure that I want to use as external storage on my raspi 4. This disk is recognized and can be formatted by my Mac, so I know the drive is good.

When I plug the drive into a usb3 port and run `fdisk -l`, the command outputs info for /dev/ram# and `/dev/mmcblk0` and then hangs, never exiting.

`/dev/sda` exists once the drive is plugged in and lsusb lists the seagate device.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Output of `dmesg` per @JaromandaX suggestion:

```
[Feb14 14:38] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.030678] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0.000015] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000013] usb 2-2: Product: BUP Slim
[  +0.000012] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  +0.000012] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  +0.008228] scsi host0: uas
[  +0.010986] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim         0304 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.001330] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  +0.000416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  +1.078004] .................................................................................................not responding...
[Feb14 14:40] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1000215215 512-byte logical blocks: (512 GB/477 GiB)
[  +0.000014] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 2048-byte physical blocks
[ +20.849826] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[  +6.950121] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[  +0.000016] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  +0.000722] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (2048 bytes)
[  +0.000805] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[Feb14 14:41] .................................................................................................not responding...
[Feb14 14:43] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD IN 
[  +0.000018] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000236] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD IN 
[  +0.000014] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000287] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD IN 
[  +0.000012] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000286] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD IN 
[  +0.000013] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 01 00
[  +0.039165] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  +0.150920] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.035044] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

Comment: check the output of `dmesg` once you've plugged the device in, and then, in another terminal, once you've run that command

Comment: @JaromandaX added dmesg output to my op.

Comment: if you open another terminal (or another ssh) does it too freeze when you run `fdisk -l` on the first terminal/session - clearly you can see `....not responding.` right?

Comment: Perhaps try `lsblk --fs` instead of `fdisk -l`? `man fdisk => manipulate disk partition table` ... is that what you're trying to do? Or - `man lsblk => list block devices` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was being caused by a power issue. The SSD in question was inside a seagate USB3 enclosure that was powered by the USB3 cable. I switched to an old USB2 enclosure that I had laying around that has it's own power supply and the problem went away.

When I was taking the SSD out of the USB3 enclosure, I found a sticker on it that said it was rated at 5v 2 amp. 2 amp is more than the pi 4 can handle apparently.

Comment: This comment really helped me get on the right track. I would have prolly never realized what was going on, since the drive worked, but just so erratically and slow.

I ended up getting an USB Y-cable with the other Y-cable end coming in from a power source while the other delivered the data to and from the PI4

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an [UAS issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/110946/33476). Try blacklisting the UAS driver for your SSD via `usb-storage.quirks=<VID>:<PID>:u` kernel parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly an issue with the adapter: See https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3070.

If it is the case, you will have to use the `mass-storage` driver instead of the default `uas` driver. There are drawbacks (no `TRIM` for instance), but at least it will allow you to use the drive with correct performance.

To do so, find out your device USB IDs with `lsusb`:

```
br@idril:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In my case, Vendor ID is 152d, and Product ID is 0578.

I changed `/boot/cmdline.txt` from:

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=087fac1d-02 etc...
```

to:

```
usb-storage.quirks=152d:0578:u console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=087fac1d-02
```

Doing this, after next boot, syslog will show something like:

```
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.085933] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 5.08
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.085980] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.086014] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.086045] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.086074] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.090111] usb 2-1: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.090255] usb 2-1: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
Feb 28 20:19:12 idril kernel: [    2.090294] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
```

This is surely not a *solution*, at best a quick *workaround*.