# External SSD fails when transmitting large files

Tags: usb, pi-4, hard-drive

I'm using:

- Raspberry PI 4
- OS: Ububtu Server 20.04
- SSD: Kingston A400 SSD SA400S37/240G 2.5" SATA, 240 GB
- Cable: Sabrent USB 3.0 to SSD / 2.5-Inch SATA I/II/III Hard Drive Adapter (EC-SSHD)
- Power Cable: Default RPI Power Cable
  The external disk is powered by the RPI.

The disk can be mounted, used and it works fine.

When I try to transfer large (500MB+) files from/to RPI with mac GUI, rsync or scp the disk fails.

When I try to mount it again (after reboot):

```
mount: /media/ssd: can't read superblock on /dev/sda.
```

After that the disk disappears from `lsblk`.

`dmseg` output:

```
[ 1372.047675] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 7964 in log
[ 1372.053265] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 7965
[ 1372.058415] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 7965 in log
[ 1372.063998] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 7966
[ 1372.069146] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 7966 in log
[ 1372.075038] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 7999
[ 1372.080179] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 7999 in log
[ 1372.085761] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8000
[ 1372.090911] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8000 in log
[ 1372.096495] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8001
[ 1372.101644] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8001 in log
[ 1372.108496] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8066
[ 1372.113650] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8066 in log
[ 1372.119233] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8067
[ 1372.124371] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8067 in log
[ 1372.129960] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8068
[ 1372.130075] buffer_io_error: 279 callbacks suppressed
[ 1372.130080] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost async page write
[ 1372.135110] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8068 in log
[ 1372.142536] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, lost async page write
[ 1372.142544] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 2, lost async page write
[ 1372.148108] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8069
[ 1372.148111] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8069 in log
[ 1372.148116] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8070
[ 1372.155552] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 56, lost async page write
[ 1372.162974] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8070 in log
[ 1372.168106] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1097, lost async page write
[ 1372.173684] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8071
[ 1372.178809] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1115, lost async page write
[ 1372.178817] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1116, lost async page write
[ 1372.186317] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8071 in log
[ 1372.186322] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8072
[ 1372.186326] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8072 in log
[ 1372.186330] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8073
[ 1372.192036] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 9313, lost async page write
[ 1372.199589] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8073 in log
[ 1372.199595] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8074
[ 1372.204734] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 524289, lost async page write
[ 1372.212407] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8074 in log
[ 1372.212413] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8075
[ 1372.212419] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8075 in log
[ 1372.220118] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 524293, lost async page write
[ 1372.225694] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8076
[ 1372.297001] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8076 in log
[ 1372.302592] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8077
[ 1372.307731] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8077 in log
[ 1372.313311] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8078
[ 1372.318448] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8078 in log
[ 1372.324046] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8079
[ 1372.329189] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8079 in log
[ 1372.334781] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8080
[ 1372.339923] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8080 in log
[ 1372.345515] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8081
[ 1372.350656] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8081 in log
[ 1372.356234] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8082
[ 1372.361371] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8082 in log
[ 1372.366962] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8083
[ 1372.372103] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8083 in log
[ 1372.377694] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8084
[ 1372.382834] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8084 in log
[ 1372.388446] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8085
[ 1372.393607] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8085 in log
[ 1372.399200] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8086
[ 1372.404342] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8086 in log
[ 1372.409933] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8087
[ 1372.415074] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8087 in log
[ 1372.420653] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8088
[ 1372.425795] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8088 in log
[ 1372.431386] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8089
[ 1372.436527] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8089 in log
[ 1372.442118] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8090
[ 1372.447259] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8090 in log
[ 1372.452849] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8091
[ 1372.457989] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8091 in log
[ 1372.463580] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8092
[ 1372.468721] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8092 in log
[ 1372.474312] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8093
[ 1372.479451] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8093 in log
[ 1372.485041] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8094
[ 1372.490181] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8094 in log
[ 1372.495771] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8095
[ 1372.500910] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8095 in log
[ 1372.506502] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8096
[ 1372.511642] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8096 in log
[ 1372.517234] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8097
[ 1372.522374] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8097 in log
[ 1372.528737] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8098
[ 1372.533869] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8098 in log
[ 1372.539460] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8099
[ 1372.544602] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8099 in log
[ 1372.550194] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8100
[ 1372.555334] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8100 in log
[ 1372.560924] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8101
[ 1372.566065] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8101 in log
[ 1372.571657] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8102
[ 1372.576796] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8102 in log
[ 1372.582386] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8103
[ 1372.587526] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8103 in log
[ 1372.593117] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8104
[ 1372.598257] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8104 in log
[ 1372.603847] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8105
[ 1372.608988] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8105 in log
[ 1372.614578] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8106
[ 1372.619719] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8106 in log
[ 1372.625311] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8107
[ 1372.630452] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8107 in log
[ 1372.636047] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8108
[ 1372.641193] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8108 in log
[ 1372.646806] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8109
[ 1372.651957] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8109 in log
[ 1372.657549] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8110
[ 1372.662689] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8110 in log
[ 1372.668267] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8111
[ 1372.673414] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8111 in log
[ 1372.679015] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8112
[ 1372.684167] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8112 in log
[ 1372.689762] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8113
[ 1372.694902] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8113 in log
[ 1372.700487] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8114
[ 1372.705632] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8114 in log
[ 1372.711231] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8115
[ 1372.716377] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8115 in log
[ 1372.721973] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8116
[ 1372.727121] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8116 in log
[ 1372.732715] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8117
[ 1372.737856] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8117 in log
[ 1372.743451] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8118
[ 1372.748596] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8118 in log
[ 1372.754194] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8119
[ 1372.759335] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8119 in log
[ 1372.764925] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8120
[ 1372.770084] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8120 in log
[ 1372.775689] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8121
[ 1372.780837] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8121 in log
[ 1372.786433] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8122
[ 1372.791575] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8122 in log
[ 1372.797188] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8123
[ 1372.802360] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8123 in log
[ 1372.807966] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8124
[ 1372.813110] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8124 in log
[ 1372.818707] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8125
[ 1372.823850] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8125 in log
[ 1372.829442] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8126
[ 1372.834590] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8126 in log
[ 1372.840175] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8127
[ 1372.845313] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8127 in log
[ 1372.850907] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8128
[ 1372.856055] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8128 in log
[ 1372.861643] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8129
[ 1372.866796] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8129 in log
[ 1372.873129] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8130
[ 1372.878274] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8130 in log
[ 1372.883866] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8131
[ 1372.889004] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8131 in log
[ 1372.894587] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8132
[ 1372.899724] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8132 in log
[ 1372.905304] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8133
[ 1372.910442] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8133 in log
[ 1372.916050] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8134
[ 1372.921199] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8134 in log
[ 1372.926796] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8135
[ 1372.931942] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8135 in log
[ 1372.937542] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8136
[ 1372.942692] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8136 in log
[ 1372.948277] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8137
[ 1372.953414] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8137 in log
[ 1372.959008] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8138
[ 1372.964152] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8138 in log
[ 1372.969746] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8139
[ 1372.974886] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8139 in log
[ 1372.980461] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8140
[ 1372.985596] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8140 in log
[ 1372.991170] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8141
[ 1372.996305] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8141 in log
[ 1373.001880] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8142
[ 1373.007014] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8142 in log
[ 1373.012590] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8143
[ 1373.017723] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8143 in log
[ 1373.023314] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8144
[ 1373.028453] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8144 in log
[ 1373.034054] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8145
[ 1373.039195] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8145 in log
[ 1373.044778] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8146
[ 1373.049917] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8146 in log
[ 1373.055510] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8147
[ 1373.060654] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8147 in log
[ 1373.066249] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8148
[ 1373.071389] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8148 in log
[ 1373.076979] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8149
[ 1373.082120] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8149 in log
[ 1373.087699] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8150
[ 1373.092850] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8150 in log
[ 1373.098446] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8151
[ 1373.103584] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8151 in log
[ 1373.109174] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8152
[ 1373.114315] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8152 in log
[ 1373.119908] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8153
[ 1373.125049] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8153 in log
[ 1373.130642] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8154
[ 1373.135781] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8154 in log
[ 1373.141371] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8155
[ 1373.146511] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8155 in log
[ 1373.152091] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8156
[ 1373.157226] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8156 in log
[ 1373.162818] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8157
[ 1373.167959] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8157 in log
[ 1373.173552] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8158
[ 1373.178692] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8158 in log
[ 1373.184272] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8159
[ 1373.189408] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8159 in log
[ 1373.194999] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8160
[ 1373.200144] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8160 in log
[ 1373.205737] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8161
[ 1373.210876] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8161 in log
[ 1373.216918] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8162
[ 1373.222063] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8162 in log
[ 1373.227657] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8163
[ 1373.232799] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8163 in log
[ 1373.238390] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8164
[ 1373.243531] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8164 in log
[ 1373.249127] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8165
[ 1373.254269] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8165 in log
[ 1373.259861] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8166
[ 1373.265002] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8166 in log
[ 1373.270593] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8167
[ 1373.275733] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8167 in log
[ 1373.281323] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8168
[ 1373.286465] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8168 in log
[ 1373.292045] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8169
[ 1373.297182] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8169 in log
[ 1373.302774] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8170
[ 1373.307916] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8170 in log
[ 1373.313509] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8171
[ 1373.318650] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8171 in log
[ 1373.324229] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8172
[ 1373.329366] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8172 in log
[ 1373.334957] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8173
[ 1373.340098] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8173 in log
[ 1373.345690] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8174
[ 1373.350830] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8174 in log
[ 1373.356409] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8175
[ 1373.361546] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8175 in log
[ 1373.367136] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8176
[ 1373.372275] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8176 in log
[ 1373.377867] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8177
[ 1373.383006] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8177 in log
[ 1373.388586] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8178
[ 1373.393722] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8178 in log
[ 1373.399313] JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 8179
[ 1373.404453] JBD2: IO error -5 recovering block 8179 in log
[ 1373.410144] JBD2: recovery failed
[ 1373.410152] EXT4-fs (sda): error loading journal
[ 1373.423798] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1373.664140] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1373.732474] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x82, streams are being disabled already
[ 1709.344413] rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 1709.344422] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050000)
[ 1711.360394] rpi_firmware_get_throttled: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 1711.360402] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[ 3509.638575] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050000)
[ 3511.654595] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[ 5307.919270] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[ 5311.948967] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

`dmesg` output after reboot (disk not mounted):

```
[    1.722405] Run /init as init process
[    1.724451] random: fast init done
[    1.748165] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.777545] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.780440] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.780472] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    1.794824] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address 5048
[    1.795503] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 Y032V 28.9 GiB
[    1.800552]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.851335] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.872886] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561, bcdDevice= 2.04
[    1.872905] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.872917] usb 2-1: Product: SABRENT
[    1.872928] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[    1.872939] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: DB9876543214E
[    1.999087] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.081598] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.097870] scsi host0: uas
[    2.099381] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    2.099530] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT                   0204 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    2.101344] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.153547] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    2.153566] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.153577] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.155372] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.155569] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.593886] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 937703088 512-byte logical blocks: (480 GB/447 GiB)
[    2.593903] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    2.594109] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.594123] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[    2.594520] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.595209] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[    2.621168] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.012094] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.113405] random: crng init done
[    4.113416] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   33.771008] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD IN
[   33.771019] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 35 b8 00 00 48 00
[   33.787001] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[   33.915622] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   33.938905] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[   64.491001] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD IN
[   64.491012] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 35 b8 00 00 48 00
[   64.507000] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[   64.635598] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   64.658933] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[...]
[  133.271532] systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
[  133.289460] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[  133.297549] systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[  133.405859] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[  133.474407] systemd-journald[918]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[  133.482278] systemd-journald[918]: File /var/log/journal/b34149456f3d4b6d8d30286c15dcd51a/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[  134.777770] rpivid-mem feb00000.hevc-decoder: rpivid-hevcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb00000 length 0x00010000
[  134.778322] rpivid-mem feb10000.rpivid-local-intc: rpivid-intcmem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb10000 length 0x00001000
[  134.778735] rpivid-mem feb20000.h264-decoder: rpivid-h264mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb20000 length 0x00010000
[  134.779185] rpivid-mem feb30000.vp9-decoder: rpivid-vp9mem initialised: Registers at 0xfeb30000 length 0x00010000
[  134.848378] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[  134.856108] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  134.857130] vc_sm_cma: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  134.879524] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[  134.879546] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[  134.887466] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[  135.005710] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  135.090906] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.101305] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
[  135.105423] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[  135.115463] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[  135.151470] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.151536] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.192831] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.201398] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[  135.201919] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[  135.202320] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[  135.202650] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[  135.202676] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[  135.202695] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[  135.202709] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[  135.202734] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[  135.202940] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[  135.206713] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.208182] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  135.224095] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[  135.224139] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[  135.231609] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[  135.231658] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[  135.238510] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[  135.238561] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[  135.434676] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[  135.447061] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[  135.474909] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[  135.739855] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[  135.775803] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Mar 23 2020 02:19:54 version 7.45.206 (r725000 CY) FWID 01-88ee44ea
[  135.992901] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  135.993037] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[  135.993047] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  135.993070] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  135.993085] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  135.993110] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  136.959162] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[  138.465079] alua: device handler registered
[  138.471895] emc: device handler registered
[  138.478590] rdac: device handler registered
[  140.078179] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.323:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.078196] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.323:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.078477] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.323:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=1609 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.083719] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.331:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1613 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.083736] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.331:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1613 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.102388] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.347:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=1616 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.102405] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.347:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=1616 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.102415] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.347:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=1616 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.108962] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.355:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1610 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  140.112763] audit: type=1400 audit(1616017007.359:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1617 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  143.007027] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[  145.023116] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[  149.055028] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[  173.035003] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD IN
[  173.035015] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#26 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 35 b8 00 00 48 00
[  173.051000] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[  173.179610] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  173.203030] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[  174.195082] bcmgenet: Skipping UMAC reset
[  174.196710] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII
[  174.196964] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[  175.263164] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[  178.640591] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[  179.109006] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[  179.295262] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[  179.295329] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  195.423069] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[ 1032.067105] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[ 1036.099036] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

Shoud I try a different cable (maybe self-powered)?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my RPI4.
First: while using Argon M2 case, there is NO OTHER USB SDD that works on long run - even I tried with quirks - the same issue.
When I used RPI with microSD then there is no problem to attach the same USB SSD.
I suspect the USB power output - this is not a problem with my power supply as I have 5.3V/10A and when I measure on GPIO pins with both SSD connected it always 5V

I am not able to prove my point but the only common point for me was: 2 SSD connected to USB - irrespective if they were on the same USB3 or USB2 or mixed.

When I simulated lower voltage (with 1 SDD connected) the /var/log/messages were similar - too low voltage for SSD USB shows the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Your logs show that your system repeatedly gets under-voltage warnings. Find a better power supply and cable, and verify that you don't get such warnings.

If the under-voltage warnings are gone and the SSD is still not working properly, the next thing to try is to switch from UAS driver to mass storage driver using [`usb-storage.quirks=<VID>:<PID>:u`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/121810/33476) kernel parameter in `cmdline.txt`.