# Raspberry Pi 4 only boots from SSD over USB 2.0, but not over USB 3.0

Tags: usb3

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB of RAM which I want to boot from SSD (Samsung 850 EVO 120 GB).

I have installed the most recent EEPROM and believe it is configured correctly:

```
BCM2711 detected                   
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
Checking for updates in /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/stable
BOOTLOADER: up-to-date
CURRENT: Tue Feb 16 13:23:36 UTC 2021 (1613481816)
 LATEST: Tue Feb 16 13:23:36 UTC 2021 (1613481816)
RELEASE: stable                    
VL805: up-to-date
CURRENT: 000138a1
LATEST: 000138a1
```

Configuration:

```
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
[all]
BOOT_ORDER=0xf14
```

The SSD is connected with a SATA-USB3 Adapter to the PIs USB ports (1 Data and 1 Power plug).
When connected to USB 2.0, everything works fine. But when connected to USB 3.0 the raspberry pi never boots fully. At least I can not connect to it over Ethernet, unfortunately I do not have a micro-HDMI cable to check for diagnostics.

Is this a known problem? What can I do to make it boot over USB 3.0?

Comment: The problem is known for a long time, it sometimes leads to [non-working drives](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/121819/raspberry-pi-4-suddenly-wont-recognize-nvme-on-usb3-port), and sometimes to [poor performance](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/110933/33476)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling without any success for days, I found the solution right after posting the question.

[The details are posted here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931)

The gist: find out the PID/VID of your SATA adapter.

```
lsusb && lsusb -t
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
```

The important information is 152d:0578.

Now edit /boot/cmdline.txt and add the following at the beginning of the line:

```
usb-storage.quirks=152d:0578:u ...
```