# SSD "failing" after use with RPi4 for a while

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, boot-issues

I've been playing with booting from SSDs in my RPi4s for systems that have heavy log-activity. I've been using this drive: `Kingston 2,5" SATA SSD A400 480GB` together with a 'generic' SATA to USB3.0 adapter (dual USB type A plugs - one for power delivery, one for data ([link](https://www.berrybase.de/computer/externe-festplatten-zubehoer/usb-3.0-adapterkabel/konverter-f-252-r-2-5-sata-festplatten-ssds))).

Everything was fine for a while and then the systems became extremely sluggish (taking a very long time to boot, logging in via SSH takes a minute, ...). I've tried re-writing fresh Raspian OS installs (these had worked fine for a while the first time around) but now, even at first boot, things grind to a halt near the end of the boot process. This has happened with two totally independent setups (different RPi4s, two sets SSD drives and adaptors). If I connect the drive to my computer and run diagnostics on it, it seems fine. If I boot the Pi from an SD card and mount the SSD drive it seems to work fine.

Can anyone point out to me what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Andrew

EDIT: Responding to Jaromanda's comment:
Here's the output from `lsusb` without the adapter:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

... and with the adapter this  additional line:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0562 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
```

`lsusb -t` yields the following when the adaptor is inserted:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

without:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
```

I guess the issue is due to insufficient power as indicated in the comments... Thanks!

Comment: what's the output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t`? (when the USB adapter is present)

Comment: Use of the USB adapters with two plugs (for extra power) might not work - they're generally unreliable and may (despite what they're designed for) not be able to provide enough power. Use an external power supply for the SSDs.

Comment: As PMF observes, although it may work sometimes it is unlikely you will be able to power the drive reliably from the Pi.  But DO NOT try to connect one end of that Y-adapter to a separate power supply -- you may fry the pi that way.  You need an enclosure which properly isolates and provides power from a separate source.

Comment: I would start by checking if it's related to [UAS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/110946/33476)